# In Python functions working only "top-to-bottom" order?

Tags: python

I have scripts which worked fine. I make some change and got problem. Search it and did not find answer.

It's all worked in 3.4 fine.

```
(for code in files, not for interactive mode)
(I know that in interactive mode it will be mistake):

> my_func() 
>def my_func()
-> OK

 With python 3.5 I have:

>my_func()
>def my_func()
-> NameError: name 'my_func' is not defined

Only just that way working now:

>def my_func()
>my_func()
-> OK
```

[screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAou2.png)
Where is problem?

Comment: Uhhhh. You can't call a function before it's defined regardless of which version of Python you're running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well my friend, you must define the function before you call it.

`def my_func()` should always come before `my_func()`, otherwise the function can't be recognized as an existing function on it's call.

Comment: Well it's really funny. I coded many scripts for myself. And I first time having this problem.

Comment: Yeah in many languages it must be done like this. Same in C

Comment: It's because the interpreter reads from the top to the bottom, so if it reads a function call but it isn't defined anywhere, it simply will throw an error as if he doesn't know what is it doing there.

Comment: Many languages can do this pretty well. It's a pity!